# NoSuchMethodError deploying EAR

Tags: ejb, jboss5.x, ear

I'm encountering this issue while deploying my ear to my local JBoss 5.1 server which leads to a deployment error ...
One of my war is the problem but i don't managed to find a solution.

```
    11:39:54,796 ERROR [[/pro-service]] Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) fr.mymaven.socle.log.LogbackConfigListener
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfszip:/D:/jtb/servers/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/mezzo-cpcpro/deploy/produit-acps-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/jtb/servers/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/mezzo-cpcpro/tmp/a643z2x-5nmmgf-gw7mzuun-1-gw7n0stq-ag/produit-acps-front-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war/ deployment failed
```

My EAR contains 2 WARs, when i deploy each war alone, it works.

The EAR structure :

> jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar (EJB)
>   WAR1
>      - META-INF
>      - WEB-INF
>      - Templates 
>      - Scripts
>      - ... ect
>   WAR2
>      - META-INF
>      - WEB-INF
>
> META-INF
>   lib

It's driving me crazy, any help will be greatly appreciated !

Regards,

F Jouatte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please check if your 2 WAR files have the same version of slf4j library? 
Also consider moving common libraries to EAR level.

Comment: All librairies are in the EAR level.I find the solution : Jboss library was conflicting with one of my EAR library. Thank you Ivan :-)

Comment: If the answer has helped you feel free to give it a green mark ;)